# Spark Scala Understanding reduceByKey(_ + _)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word-count, bigdata

I can't understand reduceByKey(_ + _) in the first example of spark with scala

```
object WordCount {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val inputPath = args(0)
val outputPath = args(1)
val sc = new SparkContext()
val lines = sc.textFile(inputPath)
val wordCounts = lines.flatMap {line => line.split(" ")}
.map(word => (word, 1))
.reduceByKey(_ + _)  **I cant't understand this line**
wordCounts.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reduce takes two elements and produce a third after applying a function to the two parameters.

The code you shown is equivalent to the the following

```
 reduceByKey((x,y)=> x + y)
```

Instead of defining dummy variables and write a lambda, Scala is smart enough to figure out that what you trying achieve is applying a `func` (sum in this case) on any two parameters it receives and hence the syntax

```
 reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 2):

reduceByKey takes two parameters, apply a function and returns

reduceByKey(_ + _)  is equivalent to reduceByKey((x,y)=> x + y)

Example :

```
val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val sum = numbers.reduceLeft[Int](_+_)

println("The sum of the numbers one through five is " + sum)
```

Results :

```
The sum of the numbers one through five is 15
numbers: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
sum: Int = 15
```

Same reduceByKey(_ ++ _) is equivalent to  reduceByKey((x,y)=> x ++ y)